# How do I change MinGW's compiled exe location while using gpp-compiler in the Atom IDE?

Tags: c++, windows, exe, atom-editor, mingw32

MinGW normally when used through the command line spits out the compiled exe of the program in the current working directory, but when used through the gpp-compiler package by kriscross07 in Atom, the exe ends up in a temp folder. I would like it to place the exe in the folder of the source files the same way MinGW would normally. This is both so I can find it easier and so that my antivirus doesn't have a heart attack every time it sees me run an exe from the temp folder.

I'm using the release version of Atom with the version of MinGW you can get through the MinGW installer at https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/.

Comment: "MinGW normally when used through the command line spits out the compiled exe of the program in the location of the cpp files"  - no, it doesn't. It puts it in your current working directory. You can of course specify a path to output the exe, via the -o  option.

Comment: Thank you for the corrections. would the line be something like: g++ test.cpp -o C:\Users\(username)\Documents\Cpp Experiments. I'm fairly new to the command line, so thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings of  Atom under File>Settings or pressing Ctrl+,(comma). In Settings  tab click on packages, under Community packages Click on Settings button of gpp-compiler, Under setting you will find ‘Compile to Temporary Directory’, Uncheck it and you are done.