# fopen() in C++ not creating the file in the same path

Tags: c++, fopen

I am using macOS Mojave. I am trying to work with files in c++ and when I use the fopen() functions it creates the file in another path. I tried using the full path but it didn't work.
Here is an example of code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  FILE *myFile;

  myFile = fopen("test.in⁩", "w");

  if (myFile != NULL){

    fprintf(myFile, "This is the file\n");


    fclose(myFile);
  }
  else{
    printf("Could not open the file\n");
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Every time it creates the file in my user folder.

Comment: Are you storing the cpp file in user folder?

Comment: No.It’s another path. On Macintosh Hd/c++/...

Comment: Where is the executable? How are you running it? What do you mean when you say a full path did not work?

Comment: So the executable is in Macintosh HD/c++/exec. I am running it with atom and I tried the full path in fopen()

Comment: And when I run it it creates the test.in file in my user folder, different from my exec path.

Comment: What was the full path you tried? Atom is probably setting the working directory to your home directory. You should investigate how to change that or run it from the command line.

Comment: I will look into it thanks.

Comment: Another path compared to what?

Comment: Compared to writing directly the file name

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify absolute path in `fopen`, then it creates file under current working directory. Current working directory is where you start the executable under terminal, not the folder of your executable file, also not the folder of your source file.

If you are compiling and running your code using command line, then you can find the newly created file under `current` directory. If you are using an IDE, then you need to ask the IDE for the actual working directory.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Atom but isn't Atom just an editor? What plugin do you use to compile and run your code?

Comment: If you are using `gpp-compiler`, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866446/how-do-i-change-mingws-compiled-exe-location-while-using-gpp-compiler-in-the-at

Comment: I did that now and it's still not working. Still creating the file in the user folder while my exec and source file is in Macintosh HD/c++/test.